# Convert string to 2 dimension array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got this string which needs to be converted to an array:

```
var string = "[[Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Caterers, Foods - Take-out]]";
```

I then need to be able to access its value like so:

```
var foo = arr[0];  //returns "Restaurant"
var bar = arr[3];  //returns "Caterers, Foods - Take-out"
```

I tried removing the first and last characters ( "[" and "]" ) but I was still left with a problem when splitting on "," because some of the value have commas inside them. Any ideas?

Comment: your 'var string = ....' statement is not valid javascript.

Comment: this is not a string -->>>  var string = [[Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Caterers, Foods - Take-out]]

Comment: I think you mean `var arr = ["Restaurants", "Restaurants", "Restaurants", "Caterers, Foods - Take-out"]`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the quotes.... It is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Split) method and the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. `split` creates the array and `map` cleans it up by returning a new `Array`:

```
var string = '[[Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Caterers, Foods - Take-out]]';

var items = string.split('],').map(
    function(s) { return s.replace(/(\[\[| \[|\]\])/g, ''); }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4LYpr/

Answer (score 1):

Since  you are splitting and trying to make an array first remove the first("[[") and last ("]]") then split the string by  ("], [").

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
> a = "[[Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Restaurants], [Caterers, Foods - Take-out]]"
> b = a.slice(1).split(",")
> newB = []
> for (i=0;i < b.length;i++) {
    formatted = b[i].trim().slice(1,-2);
    newB.push(formatted);
}
```